# jsPDF + jsPDF-AutoTable in IE10 and IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, html-table, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using jsPDF 1.2.60 and jsPDF AutoTable 2.0.32 plugin to generate a PDF containing a table with colspans and rowspans and images (Data URIs). It works without problems in Chrome and Firefox but I am not able to make it work in IE10 and IE11.

I tried working with jsPDF 1.0.272 because I read that it should work in IE<=9 hence probably in IE10 and IE11 but it didn't, I keep getting the error: 'jsPDF object undefined' similar to the error I get using the latest version of jsPDF

[image: IE Error with jsPDF-1.2.60]

I am including the following scripts:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jsPDF-1.2.60/examples/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jsPDF-1.2.60/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jsPDF-1.2.60/plugins/split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jsPDF-1.2.60/plugins/standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jsPDF-1.2.60/libs/css_colors.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jsPDF-1.2.60/libs/deflate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jsPDF-1.2.60/libs/html2pdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jsPDF-1.2.60/libs/polyfill.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jsPDF-AutoTable-2.0.32/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.tableparser-master/jquery.tableparser-min.js"></script>
```

Has anyone successfully used this library in IE?

Thanks,
Mihaela

Comment: Can you try removing all scripts and only keep `/Scripts/jsPDF-1.2.60/dist/jspdf.min.js` and see if you get the same issue? 

And by the way, you should never include the `/Scripts/jsPDF-1.2.60/libs/*` unless you know what you are doing as the dist files includes all of those by default.

Comment: @SimonBengtsson, finally it worked but not for all the cases, please see my answer below. Do you have a suggestion for troubleshooting that error. If needed I can provide the code that works, but not the one that doesn't :). Thanks

Comment: For instance, it appears that it's not supported at all. Github of the concerned issue : https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/issues/38 Maybe there is other solutions...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to export a PDF out of an html page containing a table with rowspans and colspans. I have included just the following scripts (I need jquery just because I attach a click listener to a button ...):

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jsPDF-1.2.60/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jsPDF-1.2.60/plugins/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jsPDF-1.2.60/plugins/split_text_to_size.js"></script>
```

In the original use case though it doesn't work. But there some additional scripts are being called and something might broke some of the things.

The error I get is the following: Any clue how the getters from IE get disabled?

Thanks in advance!

---

### **EDIT**

I found what was the issue: the page was displayed in compatibility mode for IE8, when I disabled this feature everything worked like a charm! :-)

[image]